# java-hibernate create dynamic tables at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, web

I want to make a web-UI where users can enter a table name and columns with their datatypes required and submit the form so that a table gets created and also want to create hbm file for the table created and i can use the class related to the table created for doing CRUD operations.

And also if anyone can suggest any other method may be without hibernate to achieve my requirement.

Thanks,

Sandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Here hibernate is only one way to create table at run time. EJB 3.0 is also useful in that but EJB have not power to create database at run time.

Comment: can you let me know.. i know that hibernate creates tables at run-time when we already create classes for each table... but i want to know how can we create tables at run-time and its respective classes also at run-time and those classes should not get deleted when the server is shutdown???